# convert a list of strings to a list of numbers?

Tags: python

I would like to convert a list of following strings into integers:

```
>>> tokens
['2', '6']
>>> int(tokens)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Other than writing a for loop to convert each member of the list `tokens`, is there a better way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call int() function on every list element in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371269/call-int-function-on-every-list-element-in-python)

Comment: @thefourtheye: a list of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use list comprehension:

```
[int(t) for t in tokens]
```

Alternatively `map` the `int` over the list

```
map(int, tokens)
```

However `map` is changed in python3, so it creates an instance of the map and you would have to cast that back into a list if you want the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = iter(list)
while i.next != None:
    print int(i.next())
```