# Converting lists in list to int?

Tags: python, list

I have a list empty2 which when prints gives the values:

```
[]
['0', '0', '0', '16', '25', '31', '36', '45', '46', '42']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', '11', '23']
['88', '84', '84', '74', '66', '58', '54', '44', '36', '26']
['14', '15', '15', '8', '9', '5', '6', '6', '7', '7']
```

The function im calling when trying to call items within this list (the individual lists) wants the values in int format.

But I can't seem to find a way to convert each list to int, without destroying the list structure within the lists, which needs to be kept. Any help would great.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371269/call-int-function-on-every-list-element-in-python).

Comment: `[int(x) for x in <list>]`

Comment: This question might not be a duplicate, since it appears the OP is asking about a list of lists of string integers, in which case the answer would be `[[int(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in empty2]`

Comment: @JCOC611 right I think this it it, my code can get through without an error, but if i set empty3 = [[int(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in empty2] and print empty 3, this list is empty,hmm


EDIT: sorry talking rubbish didn;t put empty3 in the right place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=[[],
['0', '0', '0', '16', '25', '31', '36', '45', '46', '42'],
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', '11', '23'],
['88', '84', '84', '74', '66', '58', '54', '44', '36', '26'],
['14', '15', '15', '8', '9', '5', '6', '6', '7', '7']]
print [map(int,i) for i in x ]
```

This should do it for you.

Output:`[[], [0, 0, 0, 16, 25, 31, 36, 45, 46, 42], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 11, 23], [88, 84, 84, 74, 66, 58, 54, 44, 36, 26], [14, 15, 15, 8, 9, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7]]`

Comment: this throws the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int' because, sorry quoted the text wrong , the lists are inside another list...i think?

Comment: @user3244770 its working for me.Can you post the exact way `empty2` was created