# how can I solve this problem "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, string, list

I hope that the user can input any number of x and y coordinates with decimals, and then the system can accept the user’s input to run and complete the program. I tried to run this code. When I input x=3.2, y=1.3, an error occurs. . The error message is:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/go_point.py", line 76, in <module>
    position = {'x': b[i], 'y' : d[i]}
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
[INFO] [1605762177.475666, 4304.835000]: Stop
[INFO] [1605762178.939231, 4305.836000]: Stop
```

This is my code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        rospy.init_node('nav_test', anonymous=False)
        navigator = GoToPose()
        a=raw_input('Please enter the x coordinates of any number of positions separated by commas:')
        c=raw_input('Please enter the y coordinates of any number of positions separated by commas:')
        b=[]
        d=[]
        for i in a.split(','):
         b.append(i)
         d.append(i)

        for i in a.split(','):
         rospy.init_node('nav_test', anonymous=False)
         navigator = GoToPose()

    # Customize the following values so they are appropriate for your location Hi everyone,
        position = {'x': b[i], 'y' : d[i]}
        quaternion = {'r1' : 0.000, 'r2' : 0.000, 'r3' : 0.000, 'r4' : 1.000}

        rospy.loginfo("Go to (%s, %s) pose", position['x'], position['y'])
        success = navigator.goto(position, quaternion)

        if success:
                rospy.loginfo("Arrive at the set location")
        else:
                rospy.loginfo("Failed to reach the desired location")

        # Sleep to give the last log messages time to be sent rospy.sleep(1)

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        rospy.loginfo("Ctrl-C caught. Quitting")
```

Comment: Look at `for i in a.split(',')` and then list accesses like `b[i]` and `d[i]`.  Now read the error message.  Now look at that loop with the `split` call again.

Comment: `b` and `d` are lists.  the index is `i`.  What did you get when you printed the type of `i`?  Where are you confused about the error?

Comment: They are trying to say that loops in python do not give indexes when not using range... so you cant do b[i] since i is a item of the list (str in that case) And not index...

Comment: Can you describe the cause of the error in more detail? I am a novice. When I was learning Matlab, I still had some questions about python.

Comment: Please, make the code clear indentation. Does `position = {'x': b[i], 'y' : d[i]}
        quaternion = {'r1' : 0.000, 'r2' : 0.000, 'r3' : 0.000, 'r4' : 1.000}` inside the second for loop? If yes, above two line convert the type of `i`, just add a extra line `i = int(i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
a=raw_input('Please enter the x coordinates of any number of positions separated by commas:')
c=raw_input('Please enter the y coordinates of any number of positions separated by commas:')
a=int(a)
c=int(c)
```

accessing elements in a list using an index inside the [] braces requires you put in a number. the function `raw_input()` stores the coordinate as a string (just text characters) in *a* and *c* so you would need to convert it to an integer.

Comment: also, i couldnt help but notice that you are storing the x coordinates from a using ```split``` to both b and d. shouldnt it be a->b and c->d so both x and y are stored instead of just x twice?

Answer (score 0):

`for i in a.split(",")` gives you a list of strings, since your prompts give strings. You should iterate through the lists `b` or `d` instead (I make an assumption they must have the same size, which they should be), but make sure you change those numbers in the lists into `float`s as well, as they might still be string from your prompts to the user.

Citing: [Call int() function on every list element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371269/call-int-function-on-every-list-element), you can easily turn every number in the list into a `float`.